# NestJS [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database ::: (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to run a nestjs project locally without using any docker images. But I am not able to connect to the mysql database. I can't figure out what is happening. Here I am adding my config files:

app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigureEnum } from './common/enums/configure.enum';
import { UserEntity } from './common/entities/user.entity';

const ENV = process.env['NODE_ENV'];
const envFilePath = [`env/${!ENV ? `.env` : `.env.${ENV}`}`];

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'relaxy',
      database: 'relaxy',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/common/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      // entities: [UserEntity],
      synchronize: true,
      logging: true,
      logger: 'file',
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log(__dirname);
  }
}
```

Now I am adding photos of databases in mysql:

[image: Databases]

Now I am adding photos of users in mysql:

[image: users in mysql]

The error I am getting:

[image: errors]

Comment: typeorm need a default connection like `TypeOrmModule.forRoot({ name: 'default', ...otheroptions})`

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problems.

Make sure that your entity path is pointing to the correct location. I removed the __dirname and for some or other reason I could never get things to work by passing an env file into the ConfigModule, could be that too... Heres what I know to work, with pg though.

```
type: 'postgres',
  host: this.config.get('DEV_DB_HOST'),
  port: this.config.get('DEV_DB_PORT'),
  database: this.config.get('DEV_DB_NAME'),
  username: this.config.get('DEV_DB_USER'),
  password: this.config.get('DEV_DB_PASSWORD'),
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/*.{ts,js}'],
  migrationsTableName: 'typeorm_migrations',
  synchronize: true,
```

Good luck and I hope that you get it going! :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I changed my `entities` path from `src/**/entities/*.entitiy.ts` to `dist/**/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}` and deleted my `migrations` property (which was anyways empty), and it worked. Also helped my `migration:generate`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the entity in forFeature to the module [image]